# Django Formset: multichoice queryset filter is not working for my formset after many attempts

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I have Contestant model that has many-to-one relationship with Category. I want the creator of the award to only have access to  last 15 categories of the award he has created in instantiating contestant model. That's, the multichoice queryset in the Contestant field(category) will only show the list of the last 15 categories being created in the Category Model. I have made different efforts, but the code is either not working or giving '['ManagementForm data is missing or has been tampered with']' error.

I have made countless re-factorization of codes and I have tried to adopt solutions I found on internet. But they didn't work.

```
# MY CATEGORY MODEL

class Category(models.Model):
    award = models.ForeignKey(Award, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    award_category = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
    return self.award_category


# MY CONTESTANT MODEL

class Contestant(models.Model):
    award_name = models.ForeignKey(Award, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    contestant_name = models.CharField(max_length=150, null=True, blank=True )
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='contestants')
    vote = models.IntegerField()

    def number_of_vote(self):
        return Contestant.objects.filter(self.vote).count()
    vote_count = property(number_of_vote)


#MY VIEW

def get_award(request, pk):
    new_award = get_object_or_404(Award, pk=pk)
    Contest_Formset = modelformset_factory(Contestant, fields('contestant_name', 'category',), extra=15)
    formset = Contest_Formset(request.POST)
    for form in formset:
        form.fields['category'].queryset = Category.objects.filter(user=request.user)[1:15]
        if request.method == 'POST' and form.is_valid():
            myform = form.save(commit=False)
            myform.award_name = new_award
            myform.save()
            return redirect('award_details', pk=new_award.pk)
    else:
        formset = Contest_Formset()

    context = {
    'new_award': new_award,
    'formset': formset
}

    return render(request, 'voting/get_award.html', context)



# TEMPLATE

<form action=" " method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ formset.management_form }}
    {{ formset }}
    <input type="submit" value="save">

</form>
```

I expect the output of the contestant's category field to show only the last 15 categories created by the login user.

Comment: Please display your Contestant model, you've copied Category model twice.

Comment: Thanks! I have made necessary correction.